# Is AppDomain required in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, appdomain

Is an `AppDomain` really required for each site in IIS? Or can I have a site without an `AppDomain`?

Comment: You can't execute any .net code ever without an AppDomain. That's not ASP.net specific. Just like you can't execute (usermode) code without a process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an asp.net site without app domain. It's part of the infrastructure that supports any .NET application execution and is not optional :)

You may tell us why you're thinking on getting rid of the app domain so we can give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: I am going to deploy my application on production and I was curious to know if I need to use AppDomain or not. Your pin point answer really helped me. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your IIS website requires at-least one app pool.  This is the isolated memory space for your web application(s) to run in on the server.